# Showing that if $n$ is odd then $(-1)^n = -1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Greets,

In the exercises, at the end of chapter 1.4, [Basic Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387967877), [Serge Lang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serge_Lang)

6) Prove: If $n$ is odd, then $\quad (-1)^n = -1$

How?
The working I did

$$\begin{align}( -1)^n &= ( -1 )^{2m+1}\\
  &= ( ( -1)^2 )^{m+1}\\
  &= ( ( -1 )( -1 ) )^{m+1}\\
  &= ( 1 )^{m+1} \end{align}$$

Can it get from here to $-1$?

The book shows

Let  $n =  2k + 1$. Then

$$\begin{align}(-1)^n  &= (-1)^{2k+1}\\
   &= (-1)^{2k}(-1)\\
   &= 1 \cdot (-1)\\
   &= -1 \end{align}$$

I'm having trouble with how $(-1)^{2k+1}$ became $(-1)^{2k}(-1)$.

Comment: This questions needs more upvotes. The user has showed his work which made it easy to find his mistake and help him.

Comment: Induction suffices clearly.

Comment: @Later : What prompted you to make a cosmetic change to such a low quality post without fixing the obvious typo in the title? Pushing such questions to the active queue just wastes everybody's time.

Comment: $$(-1)^{2k+1} = \left[(-1)^{2k}\right] \times (-1)^1 = \left\{\left[(-1)^2\right]^k\right\} \times (-1).$$ This equals $$  \left\{\left[1\right]^k\right\} \times (-1) = 1 \times (-1).$$

Answer (score 9):

$( -1)^n = ( -1 )^{2m+1}
  \color{red}= ( ( -1)^2 )^{m+1}$

Wrong. Note that $2(m+1)=2m+2$.

$(-1)^n  = (-1)^{2k+1}
   \color{blue}= (-1)^{2k}(-1)$, for the blue equality, answer this question: how do you define $p^q$, where $p,q\in \Bbb Z$ and $q>0$?

Comment: Ah, thank you. The proof then just died.

Comment: Whoa, never encountered those are signs in a math book before.

Comment: @usernvk Which sings (I guess you mean symbols) are you talking about?

Comment: $\in$, $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$. What do they mean?

Comment: @usernvk First notice that I edited the question and changed $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Z$. The symbol $\Bbb Z$ denotes the set of all integers, i.e., $\Bbb Z =\{\ldots, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$, whilst $\Bbb N$ is the positive integers: $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. The symbol $\in$ means that whatever is on the left of $\in$ in an element of the set on the right of $\in$.

Comment: @GitGud $\Bbb N$ is not the set of positive integers but the set of natural numbers (some people include $0$ in $\Bbb N$). The set of positive integers is better denoted with $\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: @F'OlaYinka It can be the set of the positive integers and it may also not be. In this context I'm confident it is the set of positive integers. I'm trying to get the book anyway to make sure.

Comment: @GitGud you're right but the OP is just being introduced into special number sets, it's better to call each set what it means.

Comment: @F'OlaYinka No, you're right. [Check page 5](http://www.amazon.com/Basic-Mathematics-Serge-Lang/dp/0387967877).

Comment: @GitGud I'm not sure what you're trying to show me but the link takes me to a book on amazon that I can't afford.

Comment: @usernvk As F'Ola pointed out $\Bbb N=\{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$.

Comment: @F'OlaYinka Click on *look inside* and go to page $5$.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks. Don't be confused, initially $\Bbb N$ was meant to represent the set of positive integers but things changed. Now there are a lot of ambiguity surrounding this notations. Some include $0$, some don't. Some use $\Bbb N_0$ to denote the inclusion of zero, some use $\Bbb N^+$ to denote the exclusion. I personally try as much as possible to avoid the usage of $\Bbb N$ but when I have to I choose to include $0$ to give a clear meaning of $\Bbb Z^+$. See  [Natural Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Notation)

Comment: @GitGud thanks. Trying your question.

Comment: @F'OlaYinka I'm aware of all that, I simply assumed the book would be denoting the positive natural numbers as $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @F'OlaYinka thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @GitGud Tried and I don't know how to answer your question.

Comment: @usernvk By denifition, $p^q=p^{q-1}\cdot p$, if $q\ge 1$. Or perhaps more simply and adequate (though not rigorous): $$p^q=\underbrace{p\cdot p\cdot p \cdots p}_{\displaystyle q\text{ factors}}$$

Answer (score 3):

You made an error in the 2nd equality. The relevant property of exponentiation here is:
$$
a^{m+n}=a^m a^n
$$

Comment: Solved! I completely forgot this. Wonder what I was doing during this part of the book.